# How to create Ingress Controller in kubernetes-client-java

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am developing an application where I have to spin a pod on the user demand and that specific pod should be exposed to the user using Ingress. To create a pod and service on the fly I am leveraging Kubernetes-client for java.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

ApiClient client = ClientBuilder.kubeconfig(io.kubernetes.client.util.KubeConfig.loadKubeConfig(isr)).build();

Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
```

Creating Service:

```
V1Service createResult = api.createNamespacedService("default", svc, null, null, null);
```

Creating Pod:

```
V1Pod podCreateResult =  api.createNamespacedPod("default", pod, null, null, null);
```

But I am not able to find any method to create Ingress Controller.

Comment: did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

To create ingress in namespace we have to use **NetworkingV1beta1Api** provided by Kubernetes java client library.

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

ApiClient client = ClientBuilder.kubeconfig(io.kubernetes.client.util.KubeConfig.loadKubeConfig(isr)).build();

Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
NetworkingV1beta1Api networkingV1beta1Api = new NetworkingV1beta1Api ();


NetworkingV1beta1Ingress ingress = new NetworkingV1beta1IngressBuilder()
        .withNewMetadata()
        .withName("flask-ingress")
        .endMetadata()
        .withNewSpec().withNewBackend()
        .withNewServiceName("flask-app-backend-service")
        .withNewServicePort(9001).endBackend().endSpec().build();
    

ApiResponse ingressCreateResult = networkingV1beta1Api.createNamespacedIngressWithHttpInfo("default", ingress, null, null, null);
```

Comment: OP wants to know to create an "ingress controller" using java client and not an ingress object.